# How to make column values editable/non-editable based on user login

Tags: list, custom-actions

I have a small requirement. So basically, i have a small list with the columns below

1. User ID
2. Description
3. Priority
4. Status
5. Team Remarks

Now, the above 3 fields will be filled in by any user but the last 2 fields will only be filled in by the Team working on that request. Thus, the last two fields should only be editable by team of 4,5 members.

How can i achieve this? 
Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you in online or on-premises?

Comment: You can use jquery to hide/disable fields on forms https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/202104/sharepoint-2013-show-hide-form-fields

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the Forms with PowerApps. And set some logic when every field should be shown/enabled etc.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form

http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2017/11/16/how-to-hide-fields-in-sharepoint-list-forms-using-powerapps.aspx
For the security checks there are expressions and connectors you can use.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-user
Keep in mind that it is not possible to check for the Group Membership!

Comment: he havent write if he is on Online or On-Premises, so the PowerApps should work only in Online enrivonment. I asked him for more information.