# User clicks on a checkbox, shows hidden/nested subcheckboxes

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-form, form, list-form, hide-elements

Is there a way to hide/show a sub/child checkbox group depending if a parent checkbox is checked?  I was able to do something similar with a drop down: if a user selects an item in a drop down, another group of forms will go from hidden to shown:

```
<script src="/SiteAssets/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/siteassets/jsLib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
//able to hide the sub categories...
$(document).ready(function() {
$('nobr:contains("subcat - parent a")').closest('tr').hide();
$('nobr:contains("subcat - parent b")').closest('tr').hide();
$('nobr:contains("subcat - parent c")').closest('tr').hide();
$('nobr:contains("subcat - pet dog")').closest('tr').hide();
$('nobr:contains("subcat - pet cat")').closest('tr').hide();
$('nobr:contains("subcat - pet fish")').closest('tr').hide();


//...but want to enable them if the parent is checked:  the below not working.
    $("input[title='checkbox parent']".checked(function() {
            if ($("input[title='checkbox parent']").val()=="Parent #B")
            {
                $('nobr:contains("subcat - parent a")').closest('tr').hide();
            }
            else{
                $('nobr:contains("subcat - parent b")').closest('tr').show();
            }
    });


});

</script>
```

So basically, I'm looking for something like:
**Pet Check Box Group**
+Dog
+Cat
+Fish

I select the Dog check box it will expand the sub checkbox group:
**Pet Check Box Group**
-Dog
      **(Dog Check Box Group)**
      +German Sheppard
      +Golden Retriever
      +Beagle
+Cat
+Fish

Also, the grouping of the child is associate it with the parent.  Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I made a change to the code on my original post.  The change is based an answer by @mohamed-el-qassas-mvp to a similar post [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/202104/sharepoint-2013-show-hide-form-fields).  The only difference the solution is a drop down selection.  I need a solution for a check box solution.  The code is able to hide the sub group checkboxes.  Now I just need to show based on a parent check box selection..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the following scenario:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="parent1" /> Dog
<div data-parentid="parent1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="child1"> German Sheppard
    <input type="checkbox" id="child2"> Golden Retriever
    <input type="checkbox" id="child3"> Beagle
</div>
```

you could use the change event to display the corresponding sub-checkboxes:

```
$('[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var shouldBeDisplayed = $(this).prop('checked');
    $('div[data-parentid="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').toggle(shouldBeDisplayed);
});
```

Comment: Hello Steve.  Thanks!  I made a few tweaks and was able to get it to work.  Going to count this as an accepted answer.  Thanks again!