# Show different column in New Item form and Edit Item form in Custom list

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, list, javascript, 2016

I created a custom list with some columns in SharePoint 2016 Publishing site.

Is there any way to show different column in New Item form and Edit Item form any way OOTB.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using SharePoint out of the box capabilities.

However, as you are using SharePoint 2016, you can easily show/hide fields using custom JavaScript/JQuery.

Check below links for more information:

1. [Hiding a Field in NewForm/EditForm/DisplayForm in SharePoint 2013 Using JavaScript](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0e18a8/hiding-a-field-in-newformeditformdisplayform-in-sharepoint/)
2. [SharePoint 2013 Show/Hide Form Fields](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/202104/sharepoint-2013-show-hide-form-fields) - conditionally show/hide fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the list and the fields using PnP PowerShell or normal PowerShell using CSOM and in the field definition xml you can specify if you want to show the field on new/edit/display form

You can refer the field definition xml from below URL

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/field-element-field